# Why does the Messages.app alert me to new messages quicker than my actual iPhone?

Tags: iphone, messages

The notification center clearly posts its alerts visible on my screen faster than my iPhone alerts me.

Does the path of my incoming texts change when I have the Messages.app configured to sync with my phone or does the Messages.app just alert faster, or is something else going on?

Answer (score 2):

As you are active on your compy, it gives you first opportunity to answer from there. Only if you don't bring Messages to the front does it then ping the phone.

Personally, I like it - I can type a heck of a lot faster with 8 fingers than 2 thumbs ;)

& now it can do SMS too, fabulous.

BTW, if you don't like it, I've never seen any option to change that behaviour. It *may* auto-switch if you start answering on the phone instead, but I haven't specifically checked for if it does that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the delay is intentional, in order to give you a chance to answer the message from your computer first before your phone alerts you with the same message.

Note that if a message comes in and you answer it from your computer right away, your phone will never alert you (even though if you check the phone later, the message will be there in your history).